# Why ndarray allow floating point index

Tags: python, numpy

May I know why ndarray allows floating point index accessing, and what does that mean?

```
>>> wk1 = numpy.arange(10)
>>> wk1[1:2.8]
array([1])
>>> wk1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> wk1[1:2.8]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't work any longer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43305317/2898712

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be useful, and I wonder why other classes *don't* do it the way numpy does.

One particularly helpful time when I've noticed this is if your numpy array is an image, and you have an event handler for mouse clicks which give you `event.xdata` and `event.ydata` as floats, then you can still get a region of interest using the slices without having to convert them to pixel coordinates.  For example, suppose you were cropping an image or zooming in an image by clicking and dragging a selection - the mouse position in the image will generally be on sub-pixel coordinates except for the special case where the image is displayed 1:1 scale.

As a side note, non-integer slice notation (even complex numbers in slices) can be used in their index tricks classes `r_` and `c_`, for example:

```
>>>np.r_[0:3:0.1]
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
        1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,
        2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9])

>>>np.c_[-1:1:9j]
array([[-1.  ],
       [-0.75],
       [-0.5 ],
       [-0.25],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.25],
       [ 0.5 ],
       [ 0.75],
       [ 1.  ]])
```

Comment: I agree, and I use it a lot as well for exactly the reasons you've described.  However, the python mantra is "explicit is better than implicit", so to be fair, that's probably why most other python objects don't do it that way.  Regardless, it's certainly damned handy!

Answer (score 6):

Using a floating point index in an ndarray is no longer allowed and raises an error as of version 1.12.

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
    numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

> Indexing with floats **will raise** IndexError, e.g., a[0, 0.0]. ([See 1.11 release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.11.0-notes.rst#future-changes))
>
> Indexing with floats **raises** IndexError, e.g., a[0, 0.0]. ([See 1.12 release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.12.0-notes.rst#deprecationwarning-to-error))

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, for numpy arrays, `int` is called on any input that isn't already an integer.  In other words, it rounds down.  `1.999` yields `1`, etc.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)

print x[1.9]
print x[2.1]
```

(Note that this is the same as `x[1]` and `x[2]`, respectively.)

This also applies to lists or arrays used as indicies:

```
print x[[1.2, 3.4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to track it down in the source, but looking at the documentation, what is being passed in that case is a slice object (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), and it looks like the inputs are being cast as `ints` on the numpy side of things.