# pyqtgraph LinearRegionItem get curve data between selected region

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am new to pyqtGraph and using LinearRegionItem for selection. Is there a way i can get data for curves only for selection ?
For me getting data which lies between selection is important to process.

Any help of pointer in right direction will be helpful

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
#
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
#
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(1000, 600)
#
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Multiple curves")
p1.plot(np.random.normal(size=100), pen=(255, 0, 0), name="Red curve")
p1.plot(np.random.normal(size=110) + 5, pen=(0, 255, 0), name="Blue curve")
# LinearRegionItem
#
def updateRegion(window, viewRange):
    region = lr.getRegion()
    print region
#
lr = pg.LinearRegionItem([10, 40])
lr.setZValue(-10)
p1.addItem(lr)
p1.sigXRangeChanged.connect(updateRegion)
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyqtgraphs linearregionitem has a signal called [sigRegionChanged](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/linearregionitem.html).

With this signal the regionItem emits itself when the user drags it or when it is changed programatically. Using getRegion() you can then get the low and high of the linearregionitem.

```
def regionUpdated(regionItem):
    lo,hi = regionItem.getRegion()
    print lo,hi
lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(regionUpdated)
```

This will output the position low and high when dragged, e.g.

```
9.50787175868 13.9172032101
```

If you have your red curve as a numpy array then you can slice it using the lo and hi.

```
red = np.random.normal(size=100)
red[9.50787175868:13.9172032101]
```

Which gives

```
[ 0.13231953 -0.5609786  -0.13632821  0.79973   ]
```

Slicing an index array with floats can feel a bit weird, but numpy runs int() on the indices first, basically making the call red[9:13]. See the question ["Why ndarray allow floating point index?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514547/why-ndarray-allow-floating-point-index) for more about this.

The slicing can be done in regionUpdated and then you can do anything you want with the slice, e.g. print it!

```
def regionUpdated(regionItem):
    lo,hi = regionItem.getRegion()
    print red[lo:hi]
```